# kafkatemplate is modifying message sent, need original message to be sent as it is

Tags: spring-kafka

I have implemented custom kafkalistenererrorhandler. I want to send the message to retry topic if message fails in processing. For this purpose I have added some headers to it. For doing this I am using spring-meesage.

Issue is when I am sending message using kafkatemplate it adds "\" to the string message.

Following is the code what I am doing.

```
    public Object handleError(Message<?> message, ListenerExecutionFailedException exception) {
        logger.info("Enter handleError message");
        int numberOfRetries = messageRetryCount(message);

        MessageBuilder<?> messageBuilder = MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).removeHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC)
                .removeHeader(KafkaHeaders.PARTITION_ID).removeHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY)
                .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, numberOfRetries > 0 ? retryTopic : dlqTopic);
        template.send(messageBuilder.build());
```

Internally spring-kafka converts message to producerRecord. which in output adds \ to the string.

```
2020-03-20 12:25:28.804  INFO 10936 --- [_consumer-0-C-1] c.h.kafkaretry.consumer.SimpleConsumer   : in rety :: "\"testfail\""
```

Does anyone faced same issue ? any alternatives or solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use `JsonSerializer` while your data is just a plain string. Consider to use a `StringSerializer` or `JsonDeserializer` on the consumer side.

Comment: I have not defined any serializer on consumer or producer side.

Comment: You probably use Spring Boot. Anyway: is it possible that you can share with us a simple app to let us to reproduce? Thanks